Where did I go wrong with this problem? I don't fully understand the logical relationship in partial-divative.
This is the problem:
The function $u(x,y)$ is twice continuously differentiable.And $ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}, u(x,2x)=x,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=x^2,$solve for $u_{xx}(x,2x),u_{xy}(x,2x),u_{yy}(x,2x)$
This is my approach:The problem conditions can be understood as $u(i,k),u_{ii}=u_{kk},u(x,2x)=x,u_{i}(x,2x)=x^2, let:i=x,k=2x.$ Then, consider u is a function of x, and $x=i,x=k/2,u_{i}(x,2x)=u_{x}x_{i}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial i}{\partial i}=1$
This contradicts the given conditions.
Where did I go wrong? I don't fully understand the logical relationship in partial-divative. Please just point out my problem. I want to solve it by myself later.

That messing around with too many symbols thinking this will do the job blows up when you reach $u_i(x,2x)=u_xx_i,.$ Hint: start from $u(x,2x)$ and calculate the total differential
$$
1=\frac d{dx}u(x,2x)=u_x+2u_y,.
$$
Then use what you know about $u_x$ and proceed.

There seems to be a problem with the provided data. I'm assuming that when you do not mention a specific point, the relations hold for all $(x,y)$. So, since $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = x^2$, we can conclude that $u(x,y) = \frac 13 x^3 + \phi(y)$, and from $u(x,2x)=x$ we get $\frac 13 x^3+\phi(2x) = x$, i.e. that $\phi(x) = \frac x2 - \frac{x^3}{24}$. Finally, this would lead to $u(x,y) = \frac 13 x^3+\frac y2 - \frac{y^3}{24}$, which is not compatible with $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} $.
In conclusion, as it is written now, the problem has no solution.

Seems reasonable from the statement that only the first equation is for all $x,y$. $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,2x)=x^2$ and they just missed out the $(x,2x)$. This is also suggested from $u_i(x,2x)=x^2$ in their "approach".

@Ramashalanka My point is that in mathematics there is no room for "seems reasonable" when we write down a set of conditions... Just trying to provoke a reaction from the OP.
